# Firebase database see number of simultaneous connections at node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to see either client side or server side to see the number of simultaneous connections at a node like `root.child('People').seeNumberOfSimultaneousConnections()`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API that exposes the number of listeners or clients on a specific node, or to the database in general.